# Jmeter with Oracle 12c: the ";" is unusable

Tags: oracle, jmeter, automated-tests, oracle12c, ojdbc

I have a jMeter 3.0 to oracle 12 c using thin connection (used ojdbc 7 and 7_c)  and I cannot use the row end line ( ; ). It always returns 
`Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`

If I remove the ";" from the query everything goes fine. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround for this that avoids having the semi-colon problem:

1. JDBC Request Query Type needs to be: **Update Statement**
2. The query needs to be processed as a block

```html
BEGIN

SQL Statement

END;
```

There are specific SQL structures that can't be executed as a block but still this enables having legit SQL code within the request and enhances having several statements in the same request.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JDBC_Request Sampler, you should NOT keep semi-colon as a trailing at the end of a line for SQL query,

> Do not enter a trailing semi-colon.

so, without semi-colon, it should work properly and no need to include that.

Reference:

1. http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request